# Hibernate Enforce use of Index

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

I have a table that has a well defined index, what I understand from

```
org.hiber....table(appliesTo="tableName", indexes={@Index(name=" ",columnNames=" "})})
```

is that it creates an index, now will doing this and mentioning the column names used in the actual oracle DB index give me the optimal results or is the Index never used ? How do i use the index explicitly in HQL ? Also how do i ascertain the index is being used ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what DBMS you are using.  For example, in Oracle, you cannot control which index to use through the SQL if you are using cost-based optimizer. So it is even less likely you can do anything related to this through HQL.

To assure if indices are used, it is also depends on the DBMS.  Normally I will get the actual SQL issued to DBMS, by dumping it in log through Hibernate or other JDBC logging tools (e.g. JdbcDsLog), and view the execution plan of the SQL

Comment: am i right when I say using the annotation I mentioned above creates an index rather than use the existing one ?

Comment: as per my knowledge you use sql hints in oracle queries to mention the indexes, is there a way to do the same using HQL ? My DBMS is Oracle

Comment: I don't think you can. And, in Oracle, if you are using cost based optimizer (which is default after 9i iirc), I believe sql hints for indices is no longer meaningful (please correct me if I am wrong)

Comment: @AdrianShum you can definetely use sql hint in oracle. i used them and saw the big time difference between executiun times like 1minute to 7second.